# Specificity issue in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-specificity

So I have a list of items inside a `div` with the class `book-select` and one of the `li`'s in my unordered list has the class `selected`.  According to the CSS rules I've defined, the `li`'s in the `div` has the background color `skyblue` and the one `li` with the class selected would be `steelblue`.

The problem is that the book-select class is overwriting the selected class, which I don't understand.  Wouldn't the div class be less specific than the li with the class selected?  The li is in a ul which is in the div.

#### Here's the relevant CSS and HTML:

```
.book-select li {
    font-size: 0.75em;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    background: skyblue;
    width: 25%;
    margin: auto;
}

.selected {
    background: steelblue;
}

<div class="book-select">
    <h2>Pick a book:</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Set A Volume 1, Course Foundation</li>
        <li>Set A Volume 2, Expeditionary Airman</li>
        <li>Set A Volume 3, Professional Airman</li>
        <li>Set B Volume 1, Supervisory Communicator</li>
        <li>Set B Volume 2, Supervisor of Airmen</li>
        <li class="selected">All</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is part of a quiz and the idea is that the user clicks on a book and jQuery will change the class of the selected item to whatever is clicked on, with the last li with the text **"All"** being the default selected book.  I could use a different jQuery method to change the background color, but the fact that CSS is giving me this specificity error is bothering me.

I know `.book-select li` is overwriting `.select` because the console is showing the `background: steelblue;` as crossed off.

Shouldn't it be the other way around?  Isn't `.selected` the more specific class, as it only contains one element, which is itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this selector to increase the *specifity* of that CSS rule:

```
.book-select li.selected {
   background: steelblue;
}
```

About "specifity": Simply said, one class plus one tag (`.book-select li`)  has more "weight" concerning specifity than just one class (`.selected`), so a rule with one class plus one tag will overwritea rule with  just one class.  And the selector shown above will overrule that again, since it consists of two classes and one tag.

Comment: Ah I see.  That worked.  I thought specificity worked as you got deeper into the DOM tree.  The further into the tree you get, I thought, the more specific it was.  Like a div that contains a bunch of elements would be less specific than a single element within that div.

Are you saying that it has more to do with what is specified in the rule itself?

Comment: The whole thing works according to a system that kind of gives "weight units" to the different elements which are added up. The higher that value, the higher the specifity. There is an article here, which is old but still useful: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/  And there is also this website: http://cssspecificity.com/

Answer (score 0):

Even Something as simple as

```
li.selected
{
background: steelblue;
}
```

Should overide the background for you :)

Answer (score -1):

for a possible solution, you can do this:

```
.selected {
    background: steelblue !important;
}
```

important will avoid this style from being override

Comment: This solution should only used, if you want to overwrite everywhere the background.

Comment: Like anything, there are times when Important makes sense, but in my experience they are few and there's usually a better way. Importants tend to jump out and bite you later when you least expect it